# Other ways to say "something outweighs something else"

Tags: paraphrasing

How can I paraphrase the sentence

> Advantages of this situation outweigh its disadvantages.

The sentences that come to my mind are:

> 1. Advantages of this situation are dominant to its disadvantages.

> 2. Advantages of this situation are dominant over its disadvantages.

> 3. Advantages of this situation dominate its disadvantages.

> 4. Advantages of this situation prevail over its disadvantages.

> 5. Advantages of this situation exceed its disadvantages.

However I am not sure about the authenticity of the usage of "dominant", "dominate", "prevail", and "exceed" in here. Are these sentences correct?

What are the other ways to say something outweighs something else?

Comment: Choose your metaphor before you choose your words.

Answer (score 2):

> The advantages _____ the disadvantages.

There are many words you can use, such as **outweigh**, **exceed**, **are more than**, **outnumber**, **are greater than** and more.

It's also common to use superlatives, such as:

**far outweigh**, **pale in comparison to**, **are infinitesimally smaller than**.

You can also *have* or *be at* an advantage or disadvantage.

> The house has a slight advantage.

> It has more advantages than disadvantages.

> She is at a disadvantage because of her height.

And for something that has either more advantages or disadvantages:

> It is more advantageous/disadvantageous.

Comment: "prevail" and "dominant " are not appropriate here?

Comment: Not really. I suppose you could say that "the advantages prevail", but you probably wouldn't say that the advantages are dominant or that they dominate.